# Is there a way to find out where a number lies in a range in ruby?

Tags: ruby

Let's say I have a `min` and a `max` number. `max` can be anything, but `min` will always be greater than zero.

I can get the range `min..max` and let's say I have a third number, `count` -- I want to divide the range by 10 (or some other number) to get a new scale. So, if the range is `1000`, it would increment in values of 100, 200, 300, and find out where the count lies within the range, based on my new scale. So, if `count` is 235, it would return `2` because that's where it lies on the range scale.

Am I making any sense? I'm trying to create a heat map based on a range of values, basically ... so I need to create the scale based on the range and find out where the value I'm testing lies on that new scale.

I was working with something like this, but it didn't do it:

```
def heat_map(project, word_count, division)
    unless word_count == 0
      max = project.words.maximum('quantity')
      min = project.words.minimum('quantity')
      range = min..max
      total = range.count
      break_point = total / division
      heat_index =  total.to_f / word_count.to_f
      heat_index.round
    else
      "freezing"
    end
  end
```

I figured there's probably an easier ruby way I'm missing.

Comment: Is the concept you're thinking of a histogram?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not just use arithmetic and rounding?  Assuming that `number` is between `min` and `max` and you want the range split into `n_div` divisions and `x` is the number you want to find the index of (according to above it looks like `min = 0`, `max` = 1000, `n_div = 10`, and `x = 235`):

```
def heat_index(x, min, max, n_div)
  break_point = (max - min).to_f/n_div.to_f
  heat_index = (((x - min).to_f)/break_point).to_i
end
```

Then `heat_index(235, 0, 1000, 10)` gives 2.

Comment: This is the simplest solution ... and I was working toward this approach in my head when I posted. Does it hold if the min is not 0?

Comment: Yes, it works as long as min < max (min could be negative or positive).  It would be easy to check if min < max and swap if they are not, or return 0 / raise an error if min == max or n_div == 0.

Answer (score 4):

I'm just quickly brainstorming an idea, but would something like this help?

```
>> (1..100).each_slice(10).to_a.index { |subrange| subrange.include? 34 }
=> 3
>> (1..100).each_slice(5).to_a.index { |subrange| subrange.include? 34 }
=> 6
```

This tells you in which subrange (the subrange size is determined by the argument to `each_slice`) the value (the argument to `subrange.include?`) lies.

```
>> (1..1000).each_slice(100).to_a.index { |subrange| subrange.include? 235 }
=> 2
```

Note that the indices for the subranges start from 0, so you may want to add 1 to them depending on what you need. Also this isn't ready as is, but should be easy to wrap up in a method.

Answer (score 1):

How's this? It makes an array of range boundaries and then checks if the number lies between them.

```
def find_range(min, max, query, increment)
  values = []
  (min..max).step(increment) { |value| values << value }
  values.each_with_index do |value, index|
    break if values[index + 1].nil?
    if query > value && query < values[index + 1]
      return index
    end
  end
end
```

**EDIT**: removed redundant variable

Comment: That seems to work, using the index number was a good idea ... though, I've never really understood the `<<` operator or exactly what it's doing.

Comment: `<<` adds an element to an array. so `myarray = []; myarray << "string"` results in `["string"]`.

Comment: also, that range variable is actually redundant, you could dispense with it and just return index from inside that `if`

Comment: Isn't this terribly inefficient compared to the original solution with `(min..max).count` improved as suggested by dantswain? This one runs in O(n) where the original solution has constant runtime (n being (max-min)/increment).